# How to set the size of X image using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there I'm currently working on a catalog of sorts and am currently trying to make an image enlarge when it's clicked on. I have the JavaScript functionality like onmouseclick working perfectly but can't seem to get the JQuery that's inside the enlarge function to target an individual image. For example if I try to enlarge the second record in the list all images get enlarged, not just the one I selected.

Here is the function as you can see below I'm setting the product image width and height. I want to have functionality like the above styles using x. Is there a way to achieve this? Any information would be appreciated.

```
function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.fontSize = "15px";
    x.style.maxWidth = "90%";
    x.style.height = "auto";
    $('.product').width(350);
    $('.product').height(250);
}
```

Also the information that's being set by the x.styles in the function above is being used in an xmlParser function, I don't know if that matters at all.

Comment: What I would do is set the images with say a class "enlarge", the do something like `$(document).on('click', '.enlarge',  function({ //code});` where in the code part you can use `this.` to reference the clicked img

Comment: How are you calling `normalImg()`? Including a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question, your problem is that this jQuery selector:
    $(".product")
selects *everything* with class product, and not just the one that you clicked on. To fix this, I'd probably but the event listener on the product class, so that you can use "this" to refer to the product that was clicked, and then find and resize an img within it. The overall over might look something like this:

```
$('.product').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({width: '350px', height: '250px'})
    .find('img').css({maxWidth: '90%', height: 'auto', fontSize: '15px'});
});
```

Comment: That worked wonders Andrew I appreciate that. Thanks very much friend, I know that the question was hard to understand but that helped a lot.